# How to extract hidden field from error case

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, field, hidden

I'm using Play 2.0 with Scala and I'd like to extract some values that are stored in hidden fields.

**The form in the controller:**

```
    val recommendationForm: Form[Recommendation] = Form(
        mapping(
          "fromMail" -> email,
          "fromName" -> nonEmptyText(5, 30),
          "toMail" -> email,
          "toName" -> nonEmptyText(5, 30),
          "message" -> optional(text(0, 300)),
          "productGroupId" -> nonEmptyText(),
          "masterProductId" -> nonEmptyText()
        )
        (Recommendation.apply)(Recommendation.unapply)
      )

def doRecommend = xyzAction {  implicit request =>
    recommendationForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      errors => {
        errors.data.map(x => println(x))
        BadRequest("")
      },
      {
        case (recommendation) => {
        Ok("")
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

**The Recommendation case class:**

```
case class Recommendation(fromMail: String, fromName: String, toMail: String, toName: String, message: Option[String], productGroupId: String, masterProductId: String)
```

**The HTML:**

```
    @form(action = routes.Product.doRecommend) {

              <input type="hidden" value="@{(productGroup \ "@id").text}" />
              <input type="hidden" value="@{(currentMasterProduct \ "@id").text}" />

    @inputText(field = recommendationForm("fromName"),
                        '_label -> "",
                        'placeholder -> Messages("recommendation.from.name"),
                        '_showConstraints -> false,
                        'class -> "text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
                        )

some more fields...
}
```

**Generated HTML of hidden field:**

```
<input type="hidden" value="74.75.652">
```

But I'm unable to extract those two hidden fields from the errors. It only prints the other five ones. How can I extract the hidden ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to give the input field a name attribute...

```
<input type="hidden" value="@{(productGroup \ "@id").text}" name="@recommendationForm("productGroupId").name" />
```